# Does anyone know the NpgsqlException error code for connection timeout?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core

Does anyone know the NpgsqlException error code for connection timeout? I need to catch exception in try catch block

Comment: You can generate a timeout and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

See **Class 08 - Connection Exception [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html)**